# How to add a new dataset or new line Google Chart from a array values

Tags: php, arrays, json, google-visualization

Ok i am stuck at this point, i am trying to make a graph to predict my customers behavior along the years, so i have records in the db from 2013 till now. I created a function that query the db and return an array with the 12 months of the queried year and i loop that function through the years of records in order to avoid to modify the code the next year. My issue is that the data i pass to the chart draw the whole loop data and i need to create a new dataset or second line when the new year of records start. My array looks like this:

```
...
11 => 
    array (size=3)
      'year' => int 2013
      'month' => string 'Dec' (length=3)
      'total' => int 33

array (size=12)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'year' => int 2014
      'month' => string 'Jan' (length=3)
      'total' => int 41
  ...
```

and this is the code i have so far:

```
$table['cols'] = array(

    array('label' => 'Month', 'type' => 'string'),
    array('label' => '2013', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => '2014', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => '2015', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => '2016', 'type' => 'number')

);

$rows_graph = array();
$i = 0;
// loop for the customers list
while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_object($customers)) {

    echo 'Loop1 - ' . $rows->channel . '<br /><br />';

    // next loop for each year of records
    foreach ($years as $items) {

        echo 'Year: '.$items['year'].'<br />';


        // function(dbcon,year,customer) return an array of 12 months (ex. year => 2013, month => Jan, total = 10)
        // with the records per month for the current customer in that year.
            $data = chart_values($dbcon, $items['year'], $rows->channel);
            var_dump($data);

            // now i loop for each month
            foreach ($data as $key => $val) {
               // var_dump($test);
               // echo $val['year'] . ' - ' .$val['month'] . ' - ' . $val['total'] . '<br />';
                $temp = array();

                $temp[] = array('v' => (string)$val['month']);

                // Values of each line
                $temp[] = array('v' => (int)$val['total']);

                $rows_graph[] = array('c' => $temp);


            }

    }
    $table['rows'] = $rows_graph;
    $jsonTable = json_encode($table);
    echo $jsonTable;

    //////////////////////// graphic //////////////////////////
```

And the resulting graph show all in one line like this:

[image: Issue Snapshot]

And i would like to achieve a graph that look like this (of course with my own data, years for lines, only 12 months and total for month):

[image]

Comment: I always have trouble reading PHP, but you're definitely getting all your values in one column. Your columns are set up right because you're getting all the series in the legend. I'm thinking maybe you're just not actually checking to see which year a value is to put it in the right column. Note that the axis is a date so the date column will have to present the data for all years. ie. Jan 2013 date row will have Jan 2014, 2015 and 2016. There's another way to do that but it's probably more complicated than it's worth to you.

Comment: I think the main issue is how to restart from Jan again in the next year when building the array in the loop, actually i can add the next total value to have the second column filled, but it have the same values of the first column and both years show the same curve

Comment: If you're using a SQL database, I would probably use a sub-query or some kind of join to get the data out of the database in the format you require. It offloads the complexity to the database, but databases are optimized for joining data and crunching raw numbers like that. I can think of a few ways to do this in the JavaScript side, but I really just don't know any PHP to be able to help you on the server side.

Comment: The query is ok i think, the values returned are the ones i need, year, month and total, i think the problem is the loop that build the array for the chart, i need more coffee lol

Comment: What I meant is you could return a query result with something like [Month, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016] in each row. That way your PHP or JavaScript code doesn't need to loop back. Or you can solve it in PHP. You could store first month, iterate until you see that month again and start array index over writing to another column until you see that month again, etc. Or do array i+12+24+36 for each Google DataTable row.

Comment: That could be, but the next year i would have to modify the query to add the new year column and so on, I don't know if is possible to add columns dynamically in a quey, the second option sound logical to me thanks I will try that one

Answer (score 0):

Ok i was able to achieve what i was looking for, maybe is not clean butit work, this is what i did:

```
// loop for the customers list
while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_object($customers)) {

    echo 'Loop1 - ' . $rows->customer . '<br /><br />';

//cleaning arrays

    $rows_graph = array();
    $jan = array();
    $feb = array();
    $mar = array();
    $apr = array();
    $may = array();
    $jun = array();
    $jul = array();
    $aug = array();
    $sep = array();
    $oct = array();
    $nov = array();
    $dec = array();
    $data = array();
    $table = array();

    $table['cols'] = array(
        array('label' => 'Month', 'type' => 'string'),
    );

    // next loop for each year of records
    foreach ($years as $items) {

        // echo 'Year: '.$items['year'].'<br />';
        $table['cols'][] = array('label' => $items['year'], 'type' => 'number');

        // function(dbcon,year,customer) return an array of 12 months (ex. year => 2013, month => Jan, total = 10)
        // with the records per month for the current customer in that year.
        $data[] = chart_values($dbcon, $items['year'], $rows->channel);
        //var_dump($data);


    }
    // here is build the array for the chart
    //var_dump($data);

    $jan[] = array('v' => (string)'Jan');
    $feb[] = array('v' => (string)'Feb');
    $mar[] = array('v' => (string)'Mar');
    $apr[] = array('v' => (string)'Apr');
    $may[] = array('v' => (string)'May');
    $jun[] = array('v' => (string)'Jun');
    $jul[] = array('v' => (string)'Jul');
    $aug[] = array('v' => (string)'Aug');
    $sep[] = array('v' => (string)'Sep');
    $oct[] = array('v' => (string)'Oct');
    $nov[] = array('v' => (string)'Nov');
    $dec[] = array('v' => (string)'Dec');


    foreach ($data as $value) {
       // var_dump($value);
        foreach ($value as $key => $val) {
            // var_dump($val);
            // echo $val['year'] . ' - ' . $val['month'] . ' - ' . $val['total'] . '<br />';
            //$temp = array();
            //$temp[] = array('v' => (string)$val['month']);

            if ($val['month'] == 'Jan') {
                $jan[] = array('v' => (int)$val['total']);
            }
            if ($val['month'] == 'Feb') {
                $feb[] = array('v' => (int)$val['total']);
            }
            if ($val['month'] == 'Mar') {
                $mar[] = array('v' => (int)$val['total']);
            }
            if ($val['month'] == 'Apr') {
                $apr[] = array('v' => (int)$val['total']);
            }
            if ($val['month'] == 'May') {
                $may[] = array('v' => (int)$val['total']);
            }
            if ($val['month'] == 'Jun') {
                $jun[] = array('v' => (int)$val['total']);
            }
            if ($val['month'] == 'Jul') {
                $jul[] = array('v' => (int)$val['total']);
            }
            if ($val['month'] == 'Aug') {
                $aug[] = array('v' => (int)$val['total']);
            }
            if ($val['month'] == 'Sep') {
                $sep[] = array('v' => (int)$val['total']);
            }
            if ($val['month'] == 'Oct') {
                $oct[] = array('v' => (int)$val['total']);
            }
            if ($val['month'] == 'Nov') {
                $nov[] = array('v' => (int)$val['total']);
            }
            if ($val['month'] == 'Dec') {
                $dec[] = array('v' => (int)$val['total']);
            }

        }
    }


    $rows_graph[] = array('c' => $jan);
    $rows_graph[] = array('c' => $feb);
    $rows_graph[] = array('c' => $mar);
    $rows_graph[] = array('c' => $apr);
    $rows_graph[] = array('c' => $may);
    $rows_graph[] = array('c' => $jun);
    $rows_graph[] = array('c' => $jul);
    $rows_graph[] = array('c' => $aug);
    $rows_graph[] = array('c' => $sep);
    $rows_graph[] = array('c' => $oct);
    $rows_graph[] = array('c' => $nov);
    $rows_graph[] = array('c' => $dec);

    $table['rows'] = $rows_graph;
    $jsonTable = json_encode($table);
    //var_dump($table);
    //echo $jsonTable;


    //////////////////////// graphic //////////////////////////
```